# asp.net dropdownlist selected value display in textbox inside gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have three dropdownlist inside a gridview and a textbox inside gridview along with other controls. i want to select values from each dropdownlist and add their values and depending upon that display the result on the textbox inside the gridview. this has to be done for each row of the gridview.
I am able to get the selected values from the dropdownlist from each row, not able to display it on the textbox for each row of the gridview. 
All of this has to be done using jquery. Please help.stuck in it from the past three days. thanks
Any easy way to do this will be highly appreciated

GridView Code:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Frequency">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFrequency" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-3 it1"> 
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1.The lowest score for activity being done a minimal amount up to an hour a day.</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2.The activity is done more than an hour up to a quarter of their time at work or about 2 hours a day</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3.The activity is done for at least half of the time in a day.</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4.The activity is done more than half of the day</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5.The activity is done three quarters of the day</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="6">6.The highest score for the person performing the task all day alone</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Probability">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProbability" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-4 it2"> 
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1.The lowest score for any low probability of injury</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2.There is a remote chance of injury</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3.There is an occasional chance of injury</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4.There is a probable chance of injury</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5.There is a likely chance of injury.</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="6">6.The highest score for any high probability of injury occurring.</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Severity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dllSeverity" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-3 it3" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dllSeverity_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1.The lowest score for any minor injuries such as minor cuts, scrapes requiring first-aid.</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2.Multiple first Aid, with possible health care visit with no lost time.</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3.Potential for medical aid cases and/or resulting in few days of lost time injuries.</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4.Long term lost time injury</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5.The highest score for any major injuries such as fatalities/critical injuries</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hazard Rating">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbHazRat" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-1 form-control it4"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>   
        </asp:GridView>
```

jquery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var a, b, c;

            $('.it1').change(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                a = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

                var d = $('#<%=gvCHA.ClientID%>').find('input:text[id*="tbHazRat"]');
                d.val(a);   
            });

            $('.it2').change(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                b = row.find('option:selected').val();
                alert(b);
            });

            $('.it3').change(function () {
                c = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
               // alert(a);
            });

            var e = a + b + c;


        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of redundancies. You should make use of selectors jquery more efficiently. This is all you need to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[id^=ddl]').change(function () { // target all select element whose ID starts with ddl
            var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            $("input[id*=tbHazRat]").val(selectedValue);                
        });
    });
```

Comment: If there are more than one row in the gridview, all the textboxes values are changed. I want to set different value for textbox of a gridview row. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I put the entire GridView in UpdatePanel and using Ajax, the desired function was achieved.
Each DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged Event was called asynchronously, and a separate method called as Calculate which took the parameters from the 3 dropdownlist operated on the values and display the result on the TextBox using the GridView Row as index